# Port 25 firewall settings for only sending emails from code on windows server 2016

Tags: smtp, windows-firewall, windows-server-2016

I installed SMTP server on my Windows Server 2016.
This server will be used by my web application to send emails to the users.
For receiving emails I use different mail servers (MX records points to these different servers)

My question is about setting firewall. Will it be enough to open port 25 for only outbound? Do I have to open port 25 for inbound as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Superuser!

This will work just fine for your purposes. **You're correct, you have no need of port 25 inbound since you are not receiving mail.**

All of the other verification stuff that mail servers will do to make sure you're not *a dirty spammer* involves checks against your server's reverse DNS, SPF/DKIM/DMARC, and the message contents - none of which involve connecting back to your mail server.